# Non-ascii characters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sdna

I have posted a question about the use of sDNA in ArcGIS. It is said the problem is caused by non-ascii characters. I tired to modify the shapefile and kept the Object ID and Shape length only. However, the analysis still failed. Here is the attribute table of the data and the steps I tried.
[image]

Comment: Does your folder structure still contain any chinese characters (i.e. Onedrive/文件...)? Maybe changing the path to have latin characters only might work.

Comment: I changed the folder and the storing path to the ones have latin characters only. However, the error still exists.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please revise your original question, which remains open but unanswered, rather than asking a new one in this situation.  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question.

Comment: Hi, are you able to copy all the text from the "Errors and warnings" part of the dialog in the screenshot above (as it scrolls out of view) and add it to your question? thank you

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 131, in execute
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA\runsdnacommand.py", line 117, in runsdnacommand
    ferr.poll()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA\runsdnacommand.py", line 76, in poll
    char = ensure_string(self.q.get_nowait())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA\runsdnacommand.py", line 35, in ensure_string
    return str(byte,"ascii")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
 Failed to execute (sDNAIntegral).

Comment: I have just changed the language of my Windows setting. There is still an error, but the error message is different:
 Process did not complete successfully
 Failed to execute (sDNAPrepare).

Comment: I looked for the detailed system message.

Comment: ERR: Traceback (most recent call last):
ERR:   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA\bin\\sdnaintegral.py", line 4, in <module>
ERR:     commandline_integral_prepare("sdnaintegral")
ERR:   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA\commandline_integral_prepare.py", line 103, in commandline_integral_prepare
ERR:     dll = options.dll)
ERR:   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA\runcalculation.py", line 58, in runcalculation
ERR:     tablecollection1d = TableCollection()
ERR:   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA\sdnapy.py", line 229, in __init__
ERR:     self.dll=_dll()

Comment: ERR:   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA\sdnapy.py", line 44, in _dll
ERR:     __initialize_dll()
ERR:   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA\sdnapy.py", line 84, in __initialize_dll
ERR:     __dll_instance = windll.LoadLibrary(str(__sdna_dll_path))
ERR:   File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 442, in LoadLibrary
ERR:     return self._dlltype(name)
ERR:   File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
ERR:     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

Comment: ERR: OSError: [WinError 14001] The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool f
or more detail
External command completed